# How to make an appimage into a desktop executable and put into applicatio tray in Xubuntu Linux?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-icons, appimage

I have an appimage for a game that I'd like to access via the application launcher in Xubuntu Linux and also create a desktop icon. How would I go about doing this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You will have to create a .desktop file and place it in `.local/share/applications` inside your home folder

Comment: Archisman and @mook765 yes that does answer my question, thank you!

Comment: @Cranberry If the above link answered your question please click the "Yes" option to the right of "Does this answer your question?" in the light blue banner above your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools like Menulibre or Alacarte allow to create a menu entry using a GUI. However, you can also create a `.desktop` launcher yourself. If it is valid, i.e. contains all needed fields with reference to a valid executable, you place it in the folder `~/.local/share/applications` and within seconds it is picked up in your application menu.

See `man xdg-desktop-menu`under `DESKTOP FILES` to learn how a `.desktop` launcher is formatted. A `.desktop` launcher should contain at least:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Application Name
Icon=Icon File
Exec=Command Line
```

Of course, substitute the values applicable for the appimage you want to run through that launcher.